# speeding up image manipulation for shadows- engineless

Tags: java, lighting

so my project is a ray-casted lighting system thats trying to implement soft shadows. the ray casting is working currently, so right now my focus is on performance of the soft shadows portion.

i use the Aparapi library to convert java code to openCL, so i can use the GPU. What is the best way of combining two images together? i've tried using a 3d array, but based on the amount of int[] objects im creating [here](https://imgur.com/a/UXSVhYN) it hardly seems optimal. i've tried flattening the 3d array but i created so many headaches for myself trying to reference a position with 2 images of mismatching sizes.

does my approach have merit? or do i need to research different ways? if i do, any information to point me in those directions would be appreciated.

code of the 3d array attempt (flattened version is very messy, and currently doesn't work as well)

main:

```
package com.example.test;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;


public class App extends Application {
    int size = 300;
    public static int shadowLevel = 178;
    public static ArrayList<Light> lightList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static int[][][] baseArray;
    public static WritableImage base;
    public static Pane pane = new Pane();


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(new Image(Objects.requireNonNull(App.class.getResourceAsStream("/image.jpg"))));
        iv.setFitHeight(300);
        iv.setFitWidth(300);
        pane.getChildren().add(iv);
        ImageView lights = new ImageView();
        lights.setFitHeight(300);
        lights.setFitWidth(300);
        pane.getChildren().add(lights);

        base = createImage(new Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7), size, size);
        baseArray = imageArray(base);

        lightList.add(new Light(300, 300, new Color(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0), 100, 0, 100, 100));
        lightList.add(new Light(150, 150, new Color(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0), 100, 0, 100, 200));
        lightList.add(new Light(150, 150, new Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), 100, 0, 200, 100));

        AnimationTimer timer = new Update();
        timer.start();

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private WritableImage createImage (Color c, int width, int height) {
        WritableImage wi = new WritableImage(width, height);
        for (int a = 0; a < width; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < height; b++) {
                wi.getPixelWriter().setColor(a, b, c);
            }
        }
        return wi;
    }

    public static WritableImage imageGradientToBlack (Color c, int width, int height, int steps, double deadPercent) {
        int endSteps = (int) (steps / 4.0);
        int deadSteps = (int) (steps * deadPercent);
        int normalSteps = steps - endSteps - deadSteps;

        double deltaR = (c.getRed()) / (normalSteps);
        double deltaG = (c.getGreen()) / (normalSteps);
        double deltaB = (c.getBlue()) / (normalSteps);
        double centerX = Math.ceil(width/2.0);
        double centerY = Math.ceil(height/2.0);

        double currentLength;

        double stepSize = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(centerX - width, 2) + Math.pow(centerY - height, 2)) / (steps * 1.1);
        int currentStep;

        WritableImage wi = new WritableImage(width, height);
        PixelWriter pw = wi.getPixelWriter();

        double red;
        double blue;
        double green;
        double alpha;

        for (int x = 0; x < wi.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < wi.getHeight(); y++) {
                currentLength = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(centerX - (x+1), 2) + Math.pow(centerY - (y+1), 2));
                currentStep = (int) Math.floor(currentLength / stepSize);

                if (currentStep > normalSteps + deadSteps) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (currentStep < deadSteps) {
                    pw.setColor(x, y, Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }
                else {
                    currentStep = currentStep - deadSteps;

                    red = Math.max((c.getRed() - (deltaR * currentStep)), 0);
                    blue = Math.max((c.getBlue() - (deltaB * currentStep)), 0);
                    green = Math.max((c.getGreen() - (deltaG * currentStep)), 0);
                    alpha = 0.15 + ((0.85/normalSteps) * currentStep);

                    if (red < 0) {
                        red = 0;
                    }
                    if (blue < 0) {
                        blue = 0;
                    }
                    if (green < 0) {
                        green = 0;
                    }

                    pw.setColor(x, y, new Color(red, green, blue, alpha));
                }

            }
        }
        return wi;
    }

    public static Image arrayToImage (int[][][] info) {
        WritableImage wi = new WritableImage(info.length, info[0].length);
        for (int a = 0; a < wi.getWidth(); a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < wi.getHeight(); b++) {
                wi.getPixelWriter().setArgb(a, b, (info[a][b][0] << 24) | (info[a][b][1] << 16) | (info[a][b][2] << 8) | (info[a][b][3]));
            }
        }
        return wi;
    }

    public static int[][][] imageArray(WritableImage wi) {
        int[][][] pixelArray = new int[(int) wi.getWidth()][(int) wi.getHeight()][4];
        int c;
        for (int a = 0; a < wi.getWidth(); a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < wi.getHeight(); b++) {
                c = wi.getPixelReader().getArgb(a, b);
                pixelArray[a][b][0] = ((c >> 24) & 0xff);
                pixelArray[a][b][1] = ((c >> 16) & 0xff);
                pixelArray[a][b][2] = ((c >> 8) & 0xff);
                pixelArray[a][b][3] = (c & 0xff);
            }
        }
        return pixelArray;
    }
}
```

Light class

```
package com.example.test;

import com.aparapi.Range;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

import static com.example.test.App.imageGradientToBlack;

public class Light {
    private WritableImage wi;
    private int[][][] image;
    private int xOffset, yOffset;
    private Range range;

    Light (int width, int height, Color c, int steps, double deadPercent, int xOffset, int yOffset) {
        this.xOffset = xOffset;
        this.yOffset = yOffset;
        wi = imageGradientToBlack(c, width, height, steps, deadPercent);
        image = App.imageArray(wi);
        range = Range.create(width*height, 100);
    }

    public Range getRange () {
        return range;
    }

    public int[][][] getImage () {
        return image;
    }

    public void setXOffset (int xOffset) {
        this.xOffset = xOffset;
    }

    public int getXOffset () {
        return xOffset;
    }

    public void setYOffset (int yOffset) {
        this.yOffset = yOffset;
    }

    public int getYOffset () {
        return yOffset;
    }
}
```

Update loop

```
package com.example.test;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class Update extends AnimationTimer {
    private long lastUpdate;
    int a = 0;
    ImageProcessingKernel ipk = new ImageProcessingKernel(App.shadowLevel);

    @Override
    public void handle (long now) {
        if (now - lastUpdate >= 8_666_666) {
            ipk.setResult(App.imageArray(App.base));
            for (Light light : App.lightList) {
                ipk.assignWorkload(ipk.results(), light.getImage(), light.getXOffset(), light.getYOffset());
                ipk.execute(light.getRange());
            }
            ((ImageView) App.pane.getChildren().get(1)).setImage(App.arrayToImage(ipk.results()));
            System.out.println(now - lastUpdate);
            lastUpdate = now;
            a++;
            if (a > 200) {
                System.gc();
                a = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

kernel

```
package com.example.test;

import com.aparapi.Kernel;

public class ImageProcessingKernel extends Kernel {
    int[][][] base;
    int[][][] overlay;
    int[][][] result;
    int x, y;
    int maxX, maxY;
    int shadowLevel;

    ImageProcessingKernel (int shadowLevel) {
        this.shadowLevel = shadowLevel;
    }

    public void setResult (int[][][] result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
    public void assignWorkload (int[][][] base, int[][][] overlay, int x, int y) {
        this.base = base;
        this.overlay = overlay;
        maxX = overlay.length;
        maxY = overlay[0].length;
        result = base;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int[][][] results () {
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int gid = getGlobalId();
        int a = gid % maxX;
        int b = gid / maxY;

        //x or y should not be more than the bounds of the screen.
        if ((a + x) >= base.length || (b + y) >= base[0].length) {
            return;
        }
        if ((a + x) <= 0 || (b + y) <= 0) {
            return;
        }
        result[a+x][b+y][0] = Math.min(Math.max(base[a+x][b+y][0], overlay[a][b][0]), shadowLevel);
        result[a+x][b+y][1] = Math.max(base[a+x][b+y][1], overlay[a][b][1]);
        result[a+x][b+y][2] = Math.max(base[a+x][b+y][2], overlay[a][b][2]);
        result[a+x][b+y][3] = Math.max(base[a+x][b+y][3], overlay[a][b][3]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not fully clear to me from reading your post what your approach *is*, so it's difficult to critique it or suggest possible improvements. Try editing your post to walk us through your current approach in detail, including relevant code snippets, diagrams, or screenshots.

Comment: @DMGregory i editted to add the code. currently for context, this code runs at about ~10 frames a second on my desktop that definitely doesn't have a hardware bottleneck.